# compat:showAsAction="always" does not work

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

I would like to know, if anyone can help me with following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_summary"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_summary"
        android:title="@string/action_summary"
        compat:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_filter"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter"
        android:title="@string/action_filter"
        compat:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

Lines compat:showAsAction="always" does not work, it's ignored. I'm using it in fragment, to be more specific, I use import android.app.Fragment;. I always get as a result "three dots" options menu.

I've never posted anything here, so far I was always able to find some solution. This time, however, I only found solutions telling me to use compat:... or android:... solution, but it didn't work in my case.

Here's my build.gradle of actual module (in case it matters):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com..."
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'
}
```

Thank you for help in advance!

Comment: In your "three dots" overflowed menu, are there these menus (`action_summary` and `action_fileter`)? If not, adnbsr's answer may right.

Comment: Yes, these two are there. As I was mentioning, these two items are there, but hidden in menu.

Comment: `android.app.Fragment` -> `android` namespace. `compat` namespace -> `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Comment: or, if you are not using v4 fragments, why do you use the `compat` namespace at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AppCompat library, you had better not use `android.app.Fragment` but use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

(Note: You can use `android.app.Fragment` with AppCompat library. However, I have experienced some problems caused by not using `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`)

And don't forget that when you use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, you also have to use `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` as `FragmentMangager` by calling `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: And `AppCompatActivity` rather than `Activity` (which I believe would be more relevant than `Fragment` in this case..?)

Comment: @SnildDolkow Yes, of course. For he is using `minSdkVersion 15`, I thought he is using AppCompatActivity naturally. But it is not sure...

Comment: Thank you for replies, but it makes no difference. I tried android.support.v4.app.Fragment with necessary changes, I also changed extend of main activity to android.support.v4.app.Fragment... And AppCompatActivity returns me an error [link](http://pastebin.com/XUBCWtMz).

Comment: @stannis98 I think at first you should use `AppCompatActivity`. The error is caused by using wrong theme. You should use `Theme.AppCompat.*`(* is something) as app theme.

Comment: @stannis93 `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`. Just do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get menu in Fragment, use and get rid of menu methods from parent activity:

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
}

@Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: This isn't an issue, I've got it all covered. My menu basically works, but it's items are hidden in "three dott" menu. But I want items to be visible as buttons in action bar.

Comment: Try to replace *compat* with *app* in menu layout. And add app namespace :     `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Comment: Use specific appcompat repo (22.2.1) in gradle. There can be some unstable versions and what is your test device? It has wide screen?

Answer (score -2):

i know this problem already.
Use `app:showAsAction="always"` instead of compat.

Comment: no. the namespace is declared in the `menu` item, and it can be whatever, in the OP's case, it is indeed `compat`

Comment: oh ok im sry. but it helped me once i had a similar prob. :)